# Python 3.6 supported for visual studio 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013

I tried to install python tools 2.2 for Visual studio 2013 for flask web development, but i keep getting an error saying,

> Unsupported python version - 3.6

My python version is 3.6.0. Is python 3.6 supported on Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Probably not. It seems that something's wrong with VS and Python 3.6. VS 2015 with the PTVS 2.2.6 cannot autodetect Python 3.6 environment and a version dropdown list for a Custom environment doesn't list ver. 3.6

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when trying Python with Visual Studio 2013.

I tried installing the version 2.2.2 and it worked!

Download and install it from the link below:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/tag/v2.2.2

Hope it works now.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

PTVS 2.2.2 works for Visual Studio 2013 + Python 3.6.